# view flipper 3 tabs

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have 3 buttons

1. Called page1
2. Called page2
3. Called page3

I want using the viewflipper that is already working fine that if I click 
on the button page1 it should send me to the page1, if I click on page2 it should send me over to the page 2 and the same for page 3..

Is anyone that can help me with this math problem?

```
setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.macro);
        2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.esr);
        3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gio);


        1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 flipper.showNext();

            }

        });
        2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flipper.showNext();
            }
        });
       3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flipper.showPrevious();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your pages indices are:

- Index 0: macroeconomic pagee.
- Index 1: esr page.
- Index 2: gio page.

Then you should do this:

```
macroeconomic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
    }
});
esr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
    }
});
gio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
     }
});
```